# Fittest polygon bounding objects in an image

Tags: computer-vision, bounding-box, object-recognition

Is there any method to create a polygon(not a rectangle) around an object in an image for object recognition.

Please refer the following images:
[the result I am looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JP2b5.png)
and 
[the original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gu1Yb.png)
.

I am not looking for bounding rectangles like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ipr7c.jpg).I know the concepts of transfer learning, using pre-trained models for object recognition and other object detection concepts.

The main aim is the object detection but not giving results using bounding box but a fitter polygon instead.Link to some resources or papers will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple (and a bit hacky) idea, but it might help: take a per-pixel scene labeling algorithm, *e.g.* [SegNet](https://github.com/TimoSaemann/ENet), and then turn the resulting segmented image into a binary image, where the white pixels are the class of interest (in your example, white for cars and black for the rest). Now compute edges. You can add those edges to the original image to obtain a result similar to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called image segmentation, which is different to object detection. The best performing methods for common object classes (e.g. cars, bikes, people, dogs,...) do this using trained CNNs, and are usually called semantic segmentation networks [awesome links](https://github.com/terryum/awesome-deep-learning-papers#image-segmentation--object-detection). This will, in theory, give you regions in your image corresponding to the object you want. After that you can fit an enclosing polygon using what is called the *convex hull*.